# Storing part of SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift, swifty-json

I'm using SwiftyJSON to handle JSON in my iOS app written in Swift.

I want to store part of the JSON object in an array, to populate the UITableView with.

The JSON is:

```
{"error":"","results":[{"id":1,"name":"test","nickname":"T"},{"id":1,"name":"Lorem","nickname":"L"}]}
```

So basically I need to store the 'results' in a Dictionary or an array of some description so I can retrieve the data when populating the table.

I can't seem to achieve this though. I can't seem to workout what format SwiftyJSON sets the sub objects to.

EDIT: I've added a slimmed down version of the code, to illustrate this problem. I've purposely set no type on the searchResults and not handled json["results"] as anything, as I'm unsure on the best type.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftHTTP
import SwiftyJSON

class SearchTableViewController: UITableViewController {


    var searchResults

    func loadSearchResults(){
        var request = HTTPTask()
        let params: Dictionary<String,AnyObject> = [
            "request": "search"
        ]

        request.responseSerializer = JSONResponseSerializer()
        request.GET("....", parameters: params, success: {(response: HTTPResponse) in
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {

                searchResults = json["results"]

            }
            },failure: {(error: NSError, response: HTTPResponse?) in
                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
                    println("Error.")
                }
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Could me maybe post some of your code, or just an example snippet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all my applications using SwiftyJSON I try to do the following:

```
if let title = searchResult[index]["show"]["name"].stringValue {
    newShow.name = title
}
```

Whenever you're storing part of your JSON response always try to get it as the correct value. I can only discourage the storing of the complete son blob in a variable as it will make working and parsing later on more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you can access underneath SwiftyJSON with the computed properties provided by Array extension of SwiftyJSON itself.

You can have access for example to an optional [JSON], a non-optional [JSON] or a [AnyObject] using respectively the array, arrayValue or arrayObject of the JSON Type.

In one of my project I declare an array of posts in my TableView Controller :

```
var postsArray : [Post]?
```

"Post" being a Model object of my own. Later on I just populate this array using one of those properties I listed above.

```
self.postsArray = persistInMem(jsonPosts.arrayValue)
```

Note that jsonPosts is a JSON object I got remotely using SwiftyJSON. The persistInMem being just a function that maps my array of "JSON" into an array of "Post" objects. The only caveat here is that I'm sure the jsonPosts of type JSON is really an Array underneath otherwise (meaning when not sure) I should have used the "array" property of SwiftyJson which computes an optional Array.

Hope this helps.